# ¿Como usar datos impresos en una tabla por js mediante formularios en otra pagina html?

Tags: javascript, html, json

He creado una un formulario en html donde al llenarlo me imprime los datos en una tabla, quiero usar uno de esos datos para imprimirlos como titulo en otra pagina html.
El proyecto es sobre el registro de talleres y el registro de personas en esos talleres, realizare cada cosa en paginas html diferentes.
El dato que necesito imprimir en el otro html es el nombre del taller

```
 <table id="info" class="table table-dark table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre de taller:</th>
                        <th>Fecha de inicio:</th>
                        <th>Fecha de término:</th>
                        <th>Lugares disponibles</th>
                        <th>Duracion del taller (horas)</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

Esa es la tabla donde se imprimen los datos del taller, los ultimos  son botones que se agregan al imprimir los datos de cada taller.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes enviar el nombre del dato por medio de su ID en la otra pagina.
Si cambias la página por medio de un botón puedes hacer esto.

```
 <a href="otra_pagina.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Enviar dato</a>
```

**Y en la otra pagina**

```
 <?php
    $id =  $_REQUEST['id'];
?>
```

Y por último solo obtienes el nombre del trabajo por el **SQL**

**SELECT FROM tu tabla WHERE id = $id**